# File I/O Uninitialised Variable Problem - C Program

Tags: c

I have the following code and when I try to run it, I get the following warning:

- warning: variable 'myfile' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
  myfile = fetch_file(myfile, argc, argv);
- note: initialize the variable 'myfile' to silence this warning
  FILE *myfile;

I have been trying to find out how to fix the warning but haven't been successful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LINE_SIZE 300

FILE * fetch_file(FILE *myfile, int argc, char *argv[1])
{
  if (argc == 1)
  {
    printf("Error, not enough commandline arguments.");
    exit(0);
  }

  myfile = fopen (argv[1], "r");

  if (myfile == NULL)
  {
    printf("\nNo file named %s was found.", argv[1]);
    exit(0);
  }

  else
  {
    printf("%s was successfully opened", argv[1]);
  }

  return myfile;
}

void print_file(FILE *the_file, char *line, int size)
{
  int count = 0;

  while (fgets(line, size, the_file) != NULL)
  {
    printf("%s", line);
    count++;
  }
  fclose(the_file);

  printf("\nThere are %d lines\n", count);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *myfile;
  char line[LINE_SIZE];

  myfile = fetch_file(--> myfile <-- , argc, argv); <----------- (warning)
  print_file(myfile, line, LINE_SIZE);

  return 0;
}
```

Ps: I'm fairly new to asking questions on this website, so if there is any way I can improve my questions and code, feel free to criticise me...

Comment: The question is fine, but there is no need to add "thank you" etc.

Comment: ...and you don't need to add "C Program" in the title, the C tag is good enough.

Comment: It's good that the `[1]` in the argument `char *argv[1]` doesn't really tell the actual dimensions. First of all because you don't know the dimension, secondly because if it were then `argv[1]` would be out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this:

```
FILE *fetch_file(int argc, char *argv[1])
{
  if (argc == 1)
  {
    printf("Error, not enough commandline arguments.");
    exit(0);
  }

  FILE *myfile = fopen (argv[1], "r");
  ...
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *myfile;
  char line[LINE_SIZE];

  myfile = fetch_file(argc, argv);
  ...
}
```

It is pointless to pass the `myfile` parameter to `fetch_file`.

The reason for the warning is that you pass an uninitialized value to a function:

This simple code reproduces this exact problem:

```
int foo(int bar)
{
    bar = 2;
    return bar * 2;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int kwork;   // kwork is not initialized
  foo(kwork);  // here you pass an uninitialized value
               // which the foo function cannot use in a useful manner
}
```

Comment: Since it's always `argv[1]` that is used for the filename, there's no need to pass `argc` or `argv` either.